# Split sound from video using iPhone and monitor

Tags: iphone, video

I'm duplicating the image from my iPhone to an HDMI monitor screen using a lightning digital AV adapter. The screen does not have audio output, while the phone is muted by default. How do I keep the audio coming from the phone while watching videos on the monitor?